# Linux search for text in files of same name in multiple folders (maxdepth 2) and generate a report file

Tags: playonlinux, grep

**Situation:**
In Linux, I have a parent folder with 22 folders of various names, each with a file of a particular name `asset.xml`. Also in these folders are hundreds of other folders with `asset.xml`in them, but these are previous versions and I'm not interested in them. I need to search inside each file for 3 tags `"legend|assetID|name"` and return the information inside these tags. They're usually on the same line so i think `Grep` is ok.

**What i've tried:**

```
grep -nr -E "legend|assetID|name" . > /dir/to/the/ReportFile.txt
```

This takes way too long and return way too much duplicated data, so this isn't practical.

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -exec grep -E "legend|assetID|name" . > /dir/to/the/ReportFile.txt
```

This returned an error with -exec missing an argument, so the output file was empty.

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -| grep -E "legend|assetID|name" . > /dir/to/the/ReportFile.txt
```

This returned an empty output file.

**Question:**
How do I go through each like-named file each inside various-named folders (which also have other subfolders with files of the same name) and extract information inside the 3 tags and write this data into an output file?

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solution.

```
grep -nr -E "legend|assetID|name" /dir/to/the/*/asset.xml > /dir/to/the/ReportFile.txt
```

The `*` in the path is the "wildcard" I needed to go through each directory. I think it only goes to that directory and not into any deeper folder...?

Answer (score 1):

Your command line with `find` was almost correct :-)

The file(s) found by `find` is represented by `{}`. The `-exec` part of the find command line must be finished somehow, with `\;` or often better with `+` which invokes `grep` only once, and I suggest that you run `grep` only on normal files `-type f`, try

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -type f -exec grep -E "legend|assetID|name" {} + > ../output
```

You may want to specify the file name `asset.xml`

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -type f -name asset.xml -exec grep -E "legend|assetID|name" {} + > ../output
```

Check the result with

```
cat ../output
```

You may want to modify the maxdepth to 3 or whatever is suitable.